# Unknown Error on Safari history Navigation using Protractor -webdrivers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, safari, protractor

I'm trying to just test history and back buttons using muliple browsers as a test and this error gets thrown:

```
    UnknownError: Yikes! Safari history navigation does not work. We can go forward or back, but once we do, we can no longer communicate with the page... (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'SFM1SKF1G3L.local', ip: '10.16.100.172', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.3', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=7.0.3, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}]
Session ID: null
```

This test works in Chrome and Firefox but not safari:

```
 it("should open find a clinic page", function(){

      browser.driver.sleep(2000);
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

      var string = 'clinic';
      var main = '.search-large-text';
      var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', string));


      expect(link.getText()).toEqual(string);

      link.click().then(function() {

        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        var title = element(by.cssContainingText(main, string));
        expect(title.getText()).toBe(string);
      });

      browser.navigate().back().then(function(){
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).toBe('Target : Expect More Pay Less')
      })


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty obvious workaround, but maybe will be useful for future readers:

```
var prevUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();
link.click().then(function() {

        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        var title = element(by.cssContainingText(main, string));
        expect(title.getText()).toBe(string);
      });
browser.navigate().to(prevUrl).then(function(){
        browser.driver.sleep(3000);
        expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).toBe('Target : Expect More Pay Less')
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an open (since Apr 2012) issue in safari selenium webdriver:

- [[SafariDriver] Cannot navigate forwards or backwards in browser history.](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3771)

And, as you can see in [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/safari-driver/inject/commands.js?spec=svnc31aea4cb6e9c8f6d75fa8533c990aba55f2d407&r=c31aea4cb6e9c8f6d75fa8533c990aba55f2d407#71), there is a hardcoded stub that doesn't let to navigate through browser's history (which `back()` is doing):

```
/**
 * Stub that reports an error that navigating through the browser history does
 * not work for the SafariDriver.
 */
safaridriver.inject.commands.unsupportedHistoryNavigation = function() {
  throw Error('Yikes! Safari history navigation does not work. We can ' +
      'go forward or back, but once we do, we can no longer ' +
      'communicate with the page...');
};
```

Comment: Alecex how the hell do you know so much about selenium/protractor lol